# Issues getting bound items to appear in datagridview via wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I have a wpf datagridview, and in one of the columns I'm trying to bind to a custom class. The class code is here:

```
public class StarfleetRanks 
{
    SBRankType chainOfCommand;
    string DisplayValue;
    string RankIdent;
    int commandPriority;

    ....

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.DisplayValue;
    }
}
```

The form is bound to a view model, and in the view model, I declare the collection here:

```
public class HomonculousViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public const string setVersion = "20151202-EXP";

    public static ObservableCollection<StarfleetRanks> ValidRanks { get; set;}
```

So far so good. Within the main xaml, I declare ValidRanks as a static resource, as such:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ValidRanks" Source="{Binding ValidRanks}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And then in the datagridview I create a DataGridTemplateColumn

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Max Rank">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox   SelectedValue="{Binding charRank}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ValidRanks}}"
                        SelectedValuePath="RankIdent" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

(and the code duplicated for editing, but I'm stripping it out in the interests of making this more streamlined.)

I've tried various methods of binding, but I still have the problem of it being completely blank no matter what I do, and the Output window isn't spitting out binding errors. I get the feeling I've overlooked something obvious, but I'm not sure what it is.

Debug Output is as follows (attaching TraceLevel High to the line for both the collection view source, and itemsSource) :

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression 
    (hash=34610869) for Binding (hash=16019739)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'progRanks'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): 
    Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): 
    Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): Attach
    to System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource.Source (hash=25825509)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 64 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): Use 
    Framework mentor <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): 
    Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 69 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): 
    Framework mentor not found
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): 
    Resolve source deferred
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): Got 
    InheritanceContextChanged event from CollectionViewSource (hash=25825509)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): 
    Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): 
    Found data context element: MainWindow (hash=10988211) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): 
    Activate with root item HomonculousViewModel (hash=16930235)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869):   
    At level 0 - for HomonculousViewModel.progRanks found accessor 
        RuntimePropertyInfo(progRanks)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): 
    Replace item at level 0 with HomonculousViewModel (hash=16930235), 
    using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(progRanks)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): 
    GetValue at level 0 from HomonculousViewModel (hash=16930235) using 
    RuntimePropertyInfo(progRanks): <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): 
    TransferValue - got raw value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=34610869): 
    TransferValue - using final value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=61567818) 
    for Binding (hash=2511739)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: ''
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=61567818): 
    Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=61567818): 
    Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=63416782) 
    for Binding (hash=2511739)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: ''
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=63416782): 
    Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=63416782): 
    Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=63416782): 
    Attach to System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.ItemsSource (hash=67884)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=63416782): 
    Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=63416782): 
    Found data context element: <null> (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=63416782): 
    Use View from CollectionViewSource (hash=25825509)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=63416782): 
    Activate with root item <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=63416782): 
    Replace item at level 0 with <null>, using accessor 
    {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=63416782): 
    GetValue at level 0 from <null> using <null>: <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=63416782): 
    TransferValue - got raw value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=63416782): 
    TransferValue - using final value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=42070525) 
    for Binding (hash=50108374)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: ''
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=42070525): 
    Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=42070525): 
    Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=13105554) 
    for Binding (hash=50108374)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: ''
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=13105554): 
    Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=13105554): 
    Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=13105554): 
    Attach to System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.ItemsSource (hash=50576745)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=13105554): 
    Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=13105554): 
    Found data context element: <null> (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 76 : BindingExpression (hash=13105554): 
    Use View from CollectionViewSource (hash=25825509)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=13105554): 
    Activate with root item <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=13105554): 
    Replace item at level 0 with <null>, using accessor {DependencyProperty.
    UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=13105554): 
    GetValue at level 0 from <null> using <null>: <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=13105554): 
    TransferValue - got raw value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=13105554): 
    TransferValue - using final value <null>
```

**Edit:** As requested, here is the full XAML. The commented out code was a different attempt to get the ItemsSource to bind properly

```
<Window x:Class="Homonculous.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Homonculous"
    xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
    xmlns:SB118="clr-namespace:SB118_CrewHistoryApp"
    xmlns:SB118E="clr-namespace:SB118_CrewHistoryApp.Enums"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="prgWindow"
    Title="SB118 Crew History" Height="714" Width="936">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DateTimeToStardateConverter x:Key="DTSconverter" />
    <local:YearToBrushConverter x:Key="YTBconverter" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="validRanks" Source="{Binding progRanks, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="BTProxy" Data="{Binding }"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DockPanel Margin="0,0,0,0"  LastChildFill="True">
        <Menu x:Name="menu" Height="20" DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsMainMenu="True">
            <MenuItem Header="_File" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Help">
                <MenuItem Header="_About" Click="DisplayAbout" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TabItem Header="History Tracker">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="34" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="17" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="82" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="63" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="label" Content="Intro Text" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="txtHeader" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="label1" Content="Ship Name" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtShipName" Margin="0,0,481,0" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  x:Name="label2" Content="Pip Style" />
                    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"  x:Name="cmbPipStyle">
                        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">RetroSlanted</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>Slanted</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>STO</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>DS9</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>TOS</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>FI</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>FC</ComboBoxItem>
                    </ComboBox>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding historyListing}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding charFirstN}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding charLastN}"/>                              
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Max Rank">
                                <!--
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data.progRanks, Source={StaticResource BTProxy}, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" 
                                                  SelectedValuePath="{Binding charRank, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                  DisplayMemberPath="{Binding }"/>                                            
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding charRank}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                -->
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox   SelectedValue="{Binding charRank}"
                                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ValidRanks}}"
                                                        SelectedValuePath="RankIdent" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <!-- <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Max Rank"> -->
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox   SelectedValue="{Binding charRank}"
                                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ValidRanks}}"
                                                        SelectedValuePath="RankIdent" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Join Date">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding charJoinDate, Converter={StaticResource YTBconverter}}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding charJoinDate}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <DatePicker IsTodayHighlighted="True" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=charJoinDate, Converter={StaticResource DTSconverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Leave Date">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding charLeaveDate, Converter={StaticResource YTBconverter}}" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding charLeaveDate}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DatePicker IsTodayHighlighted="True" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=charLeaveDate, Converter={StaticResource DTSconverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Positions and Promotions" Visibility="Hidden">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Awards" Visibility="Hidden">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It seems you are using the mvvm paradigme, are you using caliburn micro ? or somthing like it? how are you preforming your bindings? I think that if you will publish your full xaml it will be better...

Comment: added, and yes, it is a mvvm paradigm but I'm not using any framework for it

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you what is missing from your code cause this is bit complicated situation and we don't see all of the code.

I suggest you debug your bindings and figure out for yourself what is missing.
There are a lot of ways to do this, I suggest you follow [this guide](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/debugging/).

The simplest way is:

- Add this : `xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"` to your Window tag.
- Alter your  ComboBox like so :

> ```
> <ComboBox   SelectedValue="{Binding charRank}"
>                     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ValidRanks} diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
>                     SelectedValuePath="RankIdent" />
> ```

The relevant data about your bindings or miss-bindings will now be presented in the output window.

Comment: Oddly, I can't seem to resolve what it's saying now.. Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=3426315) for Binding (hash=15847393)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: ''. I'm gathering that maybe I should look at the CollectionViewSource?

Comment: looks like it, if you will post the actual output in your quastion, it could help me and others to figure it out.